# org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.ApplicationClientProtocolPB is unauthorized Error?

Tags: hadoop, hue, livy

I have kerberized Hadoop

I set this in **core-site.xml**

```
 <property>
    <name>hadoop.proxyuser.hue.hosts</name>
    <value>*</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hadoop.proxyuser.hue.groups</name>
    <value>*</value>
  </property>
```

And i ve **apache livy** to submit jobs to spark

I ve **hue** to send request via **apache livy**.

In my **livy.conf**

```
livy.impersonation.enabled = true
```

And in my `hue.ini`

```
[spark]
livy_server_host=myhost
livy_server_port=8998
security_enabled=true




 [[[sparksql]]]
   name=SparkSql
   interface=livy
```

When i open spark sql tab in hue it gives this error in apache livy

```
INFO client.ConfiguredRMFailoverProxyProvider: Failing over to <rm_1> 
INFO retry.RetryInvocationHandler: Exception while invoking getNewApplication of class ApplicationClientProtocolPBClientImpl over <rm_1> after XX fail over attempts. Trying to fail over immediately. 
INFO client.ConfiguredRMFailoverProxyProvider: Failing over to <rm_2>
WARN ipc.Client: Failed to connect to server: <rm_server>: retries get failed due to exceeded maximum allowed retries number: 0 
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
```

And in resourcemanager log i get this error

```
INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Connection from <IP>:<PORT>
 for protocol org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.ApplicationClientProtocolPB 
is unauthorized for user myproxy_user (auth:PROXY) via hue/myHueHost@MY.DOMAIN.NET (auth:KERBEROS)
```

The thing is i set hosts and groups * in core site but still it gives this error

Comment: Is there any comment on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's weird because when i changed livy launch keytab and principal with **hive** it works ( i ve defined hive in core site xml as a proxyuser as well)

Still dont know why hue keytab is not working